# Choose a right MOSFET to control a RPI

Tags: mosfet, raspberry-pi

I am working on the following system. The RPi will turn off at a low battery signal emitted by the uC (through a GPIO pin), and after a few seconds, I need to be able to turn it off completely (cutting 5V) and then be able to turn it on again. I have thought of a mosfet, controlled from the uC (3.3 logic level) but I don't know which one I can choose and how can i connect it.

any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Are you simply trying to switch between one supply (battery) and another supply (12 V)? If so then all you need is a diode (or an "ideal diode circuit") that simply selects the highest voltage. Then "Selector" would simply select the highest voltage. Take a step back and try to **describe what you're trying to achieve** without going into details like MOSFETs and GPIO pins.

Comment: Also, switching off the supply is something that experienced circuit designers try to avoid as it can introduce issues, like the supply reaching an IC anyway through the ESD protection diodes inside the IC. The way that this is done is by putting the IC (or RPi) in **sleep mode** such that it consumes very little power.

Comment: there's very many questions about switching external power supplies, here's but one, but it'll give you a good place to start your research.

Comment: p.s. the RPI already has a 3.3V out. Depending on your current requirements, you could just use that.